# tomcat database connection string with puppet (aco/tomcat module)

Tags: tomcat, puppet

I'm using [aco/tomcat](https://forge.puppet.com/aco/tomcat) module and this .pp:

```
class somevariable::base {

class { '::tomcat':
    install_from         => 'package',
    package_ensure       => 'latest',
    systemd_service_type => undef,
    service_ensure       => 'stopped',
    service_enable       => false,
  }

  $mydefaults = {
    admin_webapps        => true,
    create_default_admin => true,
    java_opts            => ['-server', '-Xmx1024m', '-Xms256m']
  }

  $myinstances = hiera('somevariable::base::instances')
  create_resources('::tomcat::instance', $myinstances, $mydefaults)

  $mywars = hiera('somevariable::app::wars', {})
  create_resources('file', $mywars)

}
```

Im setting up instances and deploying wars with hiera like this:

```
variable::base::instances:
  instance1:
    server_control_port :  '8001'
    http_port           :  '8011'
    ajp_port            :  '8111'
    ajp_params          :  
        tomcatAuthentication : 'false'
    manage_firewall     :  true
  instance2:
    server_control_port :  '8002'
    http_port           :  '8022'
    ajp_port            :  '8222'
    manage_firewall     :  true
variable::app::wars:
   instance1_app:
     path:                 '/var/lib/tomcats/instance1/webapps/sample.war'
     owner:                tomcat
     group:                root
     source:               '/usr/local/src/sample.war'
```

(I hope this helps also people searching for aco/tomcat examples)

How can I write [context definitions](https://forge.puppet.com/aco/tomcat#define-tomcatcontext) to set up connection strings instance per instance via hiera ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also tried to set up my database connection on the tomcat context (file context.xml) with no success so I finally decided to copy the per-application xml file this way:

On my main manifest `site.pp`

```
node default {

    include stdlib
    include java

    # Install tomcat and configure it for my application
    class { 'tomcat':
      install_from         => 'package',
      package_ensure       => 'latest',
      service_ensure       => 'running',
      service_enable       => true,
      tomcat_native        => true,
      manage_firewall      => false,
    }

    class {'myapp_tomcat': }
}
```

The I created my custom module called `myapp_tomcat` with these files:

`modules/myapp_tomcat/manifests/init.pp`

```
class myapp_tomcat {

    file { '/var/lib/tomcat8/conf/Catalina/localhost/Myapp.xml':
      source => 'puppet:///modules/myapp_tomcat/Myapp.xml',
      owner   => 'root',
      group   => 'root',
      mode    => '0644',
      require => Service['tomcat8'],
    }

}
```

`modules/myapp_tomcat/files/Myapp.xml`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<Context>

    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>

    <Resource name="jdbc/MyappDS" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        maxTotal="50" maxIdle="20" maxWaitMillis="10000"
        username="dbuser" password="dbpassword"
        driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
        url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydbname"/>

</Context>
```

Comment: I understand you create a class and use the File Resource to place a custom .xml with the connection string...

Comment: You could have also used the nested `context_*` class parameters. In your case `context_resources` and `context_watchedresource`.